# Run a php script in ruby on rails

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In one of my Rails application I need to execute a PHP file from the Controller of Ruby on Rails app. The PHP file meant for some database editing.

The php file located in my "public" folder

Is there is any way for doing that?

Comment: Hi daniel, I likes to do some file upload to my amazon s3 .. Tried hard in Ruby ... For that ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to talk to the process in some way, use [`IO.popen("php <script>")`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-popen). Or you could use the backticks option (not easy with the markup here), which returns the string the process writes to stdout. If you need no communication, `system "php <script>"` returns you true or false wherever the command succeded and you've got no chance to communicate further.

If you have unsafe input, use `Array#shelljoin` to escape it.

Why not rewrite the script in ruby?

Answer (score 2):

Try `php #{RAILS_ROOT}/public/php_script.php` or %x["php #{RAILS_ROOT}/public/php_script.php"]

System command doesn't work in rails but some code like the above should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

well, does `system('php public/php_script.php')` work?

Comment: HI thanks for the reply and i tried this .. But not working ..

From My Controller
system("php public/df.php")

Answer (score 1):

My problem solved by this line in my Controller

result = `D:\\rails\\php\\php.exe -f D:\\Rails\\rails_apps\\project\\public\\df.php po`

Comment: It seems that you are developing on windows where the paths are different. Have that in mind if you are planning to put it on a server with unix / linux.

Comment: JohnDel is completely correct. It would also indicate why the other answers given did not work, your PATH environment variable does not actually include PHP. Adding PHP to your PATH will allow you to directly reference PHP and you won't have to depend on installation specific configuration.