# Sharrre PHP script from Rails view partial

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-plugins

I'm wondering if anyone has tried to use Julien Hany's Sharrre plugin (http://sharrre.com/) from a Rails app? Specifically, from a view partial? The Google+ portion of the plugin requires a PHP script, which is called from the JavaScript that's in the asset pipeline. How do I execute that script from within the script tags in the view partial? Or if I need to edit Mr Hany's plugin? If so, what might I need to do?

As a side note, I've taken a look at [Run a php script in ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341363/run-a-php-script-in-ruby-on-rails), as well as the Kernel module (http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Kernel.html), but I'm not really sure where to start.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to run a php script for this -- you can look at the sharrre.php file in the download and just redo it in ruby, it looks like its using JSON, curl (try the curb gem), and some xpath traversal (try nokogiri or hpricot).

Comment: Oh. That's very true. Haha. Didn't cross my mind at the time, thanks :P