# Running php script from html.erb form

Tags: php, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I am trying to post data from an html.erb file (in my ruby on rails website) to a php script and I'm wondering if this is even possible. So far I get "Missing Template" when I try this code from my html.erb file

```
  <form method="POST" action="uam_handle_form">
          <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter email address" id="email" class="email-input">
          <input type="hidden" name="password">
          <%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>

          <div class="connect">
            <button type="submit">CONNECT</button>
            <label class="control control--checkbox">Opt in all marketing communications from X
              <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>
              <div class="control__indicator"></div>
            </label>
          </div>
        </form>
```

where "umm_handle_form" is a php file. I believe I have my routing set up correctly on rails, since if I change the file extension to html.erb the page renders albeit plain-text php.

Is there any way I can post, receive and run a php file from this form submission? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is similar to [Run a php script in ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341363/run-a-php-script-in-ruby-on-rails), although that question asks how to run php from the controller while yours runs from the view. The other question has an accepted answer, though, which is to run the PHP script from the Ruby server through system commands (backticks).

So, the steps you should take are as follows:

Submit your form over AJAX to a Rails controller endpoint which runs your php script like so:

```
@script_result_string = `php script` 
render json: { result: @script_result_string }.to_json
```

Then in your AJAX callback, read `response.result` to get the result as a string.

This might not be an acceptable solution if you're trying to run browser code using PHP. I don't think it will be easy to do so. In other words, you'd have to restrict your php code to server-only stuff.